# How to implement an external optimizer in Tensorflow with apply_gradients method?

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow

I'm trying to define some new optimization algorithm. I found an interface about external optimizer [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/opt/python/training/external_optimizer.py). It says that I need to subclass it and implement _minimize. However, I need to call apply_gradients when using the external optimizer. How can I implement it?

For example, I want to implement a custom optimizer by myself, so I look into the external optimizer and it says:

```
class ExternalOptimizerInterface(object):
    """Base class for interfaces with external optimization algorithms.

       Subclass this and implement `_minimize` in order to wrap a new optimization algorithm.'''
```

Also there is an official example that how to use this external optimizer interface in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/opt/python/training/external_optimizer_test.py#L38).

```
  class MockOptimizerInterface(external_optimizer.ExternalOptimizerInterface):
     NUM_STEP_CALLS = 5
     NUM_LOSS_CALLS = 2

     def _minimize(self, initial_val, loss_grad_func, step_callback,
                optimizer_kwargs, **unused_kwargs):
       """Minimize (x - x0)**2 / 2 with respect to x."""
       for _ in range(self.NUM_LOSS_CALLS):
         loss_grad_func(initial_val)
       for _ in range(self.NUM_STEP_CALLS):
         step_callback(initial_val)

       _, grad = loss_grad_func(initial_val)
       return initial_val - grad
```

And the Mock Optimizer are used at Line85 and 90:

```
optimizer = MockOptimizerInterface(loss)

optimizer.minimize(sess)
```

It seems that we override the 'minimize' function of ExternalOptimizerInterface. But sometimes, I need to use Optimizer.apply_gradients(). What should I do?

Comment: Could you post a piece of code to help us understand better your problem?

Comment: @LuizdePrá Hi, sure, I add some example code to make you better understand the question. If anything still confuse you, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724406/how-to-implement-an-external-optimizer-in-tensorflow-with-apply-gradients-method